# Change order in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

I'm working with Swift3. I have an App with the VCs as in the picture.

[image]

In the Mainmenu-VC the user triggers the Input-segue. User enters a firstname in the Input-VC. This triggers the Select-segue to Select-VC to select a surname and trigger Selected-segue to Details-VC.

From the Mainmenu-VC the user can also access the Details-VC. Back via NavigationControllerMechanism to Mainmenu-VC.

I want to change the NavigationControllerMechanism 'history', so that when the user enters from the Details-VC via the Selected-segue, the previous VC is changed from Select-VC to Mainmenu-VC. 
So basically when in the Details-VC, the Back always returns to Mainmenu-VC.

I have tried combining various solutions from the web, without succes.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

The View-Controller stack is stored in currentViewController.navigationController?.viewControllers.

So you should make something like :

```
//In Your Details VC :

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard let stack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers else { return }
    //get the mainMenu VC 
    let mainVC = stack.first!
    // Rearrange your stack
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [mainVC, self]

    //Now you can press "bac" to Main VC

}
```

Comment: CZ54 - Can you pls elaborate how your code is working? I mean how the system will work.

Answer (score 0):

you want to change navigation stack in this way you can manipulate

```
let myprofile = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile1ViewController") as! Profile1ViewController
   let sourseStack = self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0];
       var controllerStack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers

        let index = controllerStack!.index(of: sourseStack);
        controllerStack![index!] = myprofile

        self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(controllerStack!, animated: false);
```

to go to RootViewController

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
                })
```